# Changes in "Advanced sharing settings" of Windows 10 are not saved

Tags: networking, windows-10, file-sharing

I change settings in "Advanced Sharing Settings" in "Network and Sharing Center" of Windows 10 but they are never saved.

I turn on "Find/Discover Networks" and "File and Printer Sharing" but they become always off again despite I save the settings.

What can be the cause, how can I solve it, please?

Comment: Are you connected to a domain?  I have no problem on my local Windows 10 machine.

Comment: No I am not connected to a domain as far as I know.

Comment: That isn't a typical answer.  Its normally a Yes or No type of question.  You don't seem to be sure one way or another.  You need to find out, it makes a difference, a big difference.

Comment: The answer is no. My computer is on a workgroup.